# Is it dangerous leaving PC Rendering overnight?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, performance

Not actually a blender issue, I’m rendering in Cycles using Blender and the animation is quite long, I started rendering 13 hours ago and it’s not even at half animation. So, since it’s a job that I need to deliver soon, I thought that the only way was leaving PC rendering overnight to not even make customer wait even more. I use a 1060 6GB with 3 fans and very gently overclocked, so no temp problems (max 51) but CPU is ridiculously overheated since cooler is the Intel stock one (Intel core i5 9400F, min 79 - max 87) is it dangerous leaving it rendering overnight? I’m afraid room will go on fire or something will melt down...

Comment: Most modern CPUs and GPUs will shut down if they get near the overheating temperature. Also, they will usually slow down before reaching that threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be the same temperature no matter what time of day you render. Overnight, however, you aren't doing other things on your computer that will heat it up more. The chances of a CPU starting a fire are very, very, very low, so you don't need to worry about that. I have rendered plenty of renders overnight, and it has been fine (not even warmer in the room) in the morning.
However, there are easier ways to accomplish a large render. I recommend checking out [Sheep It Render Farm](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com). It is a free render farm for blender users. Just upload your blender file (make sure to pack all external data) to the website and then ~800 people around the globe will assist in rendering, myself included.

Comment: Rendering is very much the task that can make a poorly cooled computer overheat, by constantly taxing the CPU and/or the GPU at max capacity for long periods of time will definitely increase the chances of that happening

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos My mistake, I have not experienced overheating in my machine and I have done multi-day renders (48+ hours). Will update answer.